# Do I Need to Call AddMemoryCache in ASP.NET Core for Cache to work?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

In the latest .net Core (1.0.0-preview2-003131), I'm confused about the services that get started and also what their defaults might be.

In specific, I notice that on a new core web project, AddMvc() is called but Add AddMemoryCache() is not (both seem to be available to the app).  Going one step further, it seems that in the help doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory its shows AddMemoryCache.

Does AddMemoryCache() somehow get loaded someplace else? if not, why does cache seem to work if the service is not added?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does AddMemoryCache() somehow get loaded someplace else?

Yes. It's indirectly added when you call `services.AddMvc()`, as it's used in the [tag helpers stack](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/DependencyInjection/TagHelperExtensions.cs#L34-L35).

Comment: I'm a little baffled on that now that I see it.  If I use the Cache Tag Helper with no attributes (cache options) the content does indeed save to cache.  I would have expected to see defaults there.

Comment: Actually, I found it.  It's set in RazorViewEngine:private static readonly TimeSpan _cacheExpirationDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

Comment: I have updated my project to net6.0 framework, and it works without calling `AddMemoryCache` !